# Pip download does not see package

Tags: kaggle, anaconda, library, pip

In kaggle comp I try to store all the packages to build them later without internet connection.

At first I use freeze to get packages, then download. Problem is, that
despite 'freeze' show us /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/argon2-cffi_1640817743617/work, 'download' refuses to see it. Why? How to solve the problem or there is another way to store packages?

```
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Output

```
...
absl-py==1.4.0
aplus==0.11.0
appdirs==1.4.4
argon2-cffi @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/argon2-cffi_1640817743617/work
argon2-cffi-bindings @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/argon2-cffi-bindings_1666850768662/work
...
```

```
!pip download -r requirements.txt --no-deps -d package_files
```

Output

```
Processing /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/argon2-cffi_1640817743617/work (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 169, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/download.py", line 132, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(reqs, check_supported_wheels=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 73, in resolve
    collected = self.factory.collect_root_requirements(root_reqs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 491, in collect_root_requirements
    req = self._make_requirement_from_install_req(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 453, in _make_requirement_from_install_req
    cand = self._make_candidate_from_link(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 206, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 516, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 587, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 176, in unpack_url
    unpack_file(file.path, location, file.content_type)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/unpacking.py", line 243, in unpack_file
    or tarfile.is_tarfile(filename)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 2780, in is_tarfile
    t = open(name)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 1797, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 1863, in gzopen
    fileobj = GzipFile(name, mode + "b", compresslevel, fileobj)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/gzip.py", line 174, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/argon2-cffi_1640817743617/work'
```

Comment: Can you say more about what you're trying to do? You can't access /home/conda from a notebook.

Comment: @JohnM I try to download all installed libs into package_files
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
!pip download -r requirements.txt --no-deps -d package_files

Comment: Sure. Do you want to install these packages on a local machine that doesn;t have internet, or use them in another Kaggle competition somehow, or something else?